# How to check if Developer option is enabled or not in iOS using Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, developer-mode

For Android I used this "int devOptions = Settings.Secure.GetInt(this.ContentResolver, Settings.Global.DevelopmentSettingsEnabled, 0);" but how to do this in iOS devices?

I'm out of ideas here, Help me folks.

Comment: You don't have developer options in iOS, if you want to enable debugging you need to look for the connected device on the mac and trust it from there

Comment: When you first connect an iOS device to your Mac, the Xcode scheme selector’s destination list shows it as an “Unavailable Device”, because `Developer Mode` is disabled. As indicated by the alert, to enable `Developer Mode` go to `Settings` > `Privacy & Security` on the iOS device. Scroll down to the Developer Mode list item and navigate into it. To toggle Developer mode, use the “Developer Mode” switch.For more details, you can refer to [Enabling Developer Mode on a device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device).

Comment: What is the purpose here? Are you trying to see if the device is jailbroken or compromised? @ankit-gupta

Comment: Yes @Saamer, want to perform some sensitive operation so need to block devices which are in dev mode.